# How to pass Both Data and File from angular to Spring Controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am finding problem in passing both data and file from angular to spring controller.

Angular:

```
addata:function(data, profileFile, coverFile){    
var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('data', data);
   fd.append('profileFile', profileFile);
   fd.append('coverFile', coverFile);
$http.post(webContext+'/ngo/add', fd,{transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
}).success(function(){alert('success');
})
```

}

Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Data addData(@RequestBody Data data, @RequestBody MultipartFile    profileFile,@RequestBody MultipartFile coverFile){
LOGGER.info("===========================================>"); 
return null;
}
```

Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
I will be very thankful if someone can suggest me to how to pass it successfully.